# PyQt5 - Widgets doesn't appear when added to Vertical Box Layout

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have trained a model for tomato disease classification and now I want to create a simple GUI for that. I want to have an upload button at the top center for image uploading, and show the image at the center, below the image I have predict button that predicts the disease name. Disease name should appear between the upload button and image as a label, lastly, I have a quit button at the bottom center. When I add all the label and buttons to the vertical box layout and run the code nothing appears on the window. Here is my code, and I also put the link for model weights and one tomato leaf image for prediction:

- [model weight and tomato leaf](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NgF439m4gG4tfOc1ZD0pRc-JaUjsTHDR?usp=sharing)
- My code:

  ```
    def initUI(self):
        self.image_label = QLabel()
        self.predicted_label = QLabel()

        self.upload_button = QPushButton('Upload Image')
        self.upload_button.clicked.connect(self.click_upload)
        self.upload_button.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 25))

        self.predict_button = QPushButton('Predict')
        self.predict_button.clicked.connect(self.click_predict)
        self.predict_button.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 25))

        self.quit_button = QPushButton('Quit')
        self.quit_button.clicked.connect(self.click_quit)
        self.quit_button.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 25))

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.upload_button, 0, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.predicted_label, 0, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.image_label, 0, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.predict_button, 0, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.quit_button, 0, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter)

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.addStretch()
        self.hbox.addLayout(self.vbox)
        self.hbox.addStretch()

        self.setLayout(self.hbox)
        self.show()
  ```

When I use this create window inside a class end put initUI inside **init** function and run it gives this window:
[Window appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0iS4.png)

**Solved:** When I define my class I was passing QMainWindow, but instead, I used QWidget and it soled a problem.

Comment: please provide a [mre], not external links

Comment: The current code in your question looks dubious: why not `self.setLayout(vbox)` and `self.show()`?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

QVBoxLayout needs to have parent, in this case it should be your window

something like: vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)

Comment: I created Vertical Box with self, but again nothing shows

Comment: Did your class inherit from QMainWindow?

Comment: You didn't specify if your class object is QWidget or QMainWindow. If you class is using QMainWindow, for example:. class schooltest(QMainWindow):, the widgets in this your code won't display, replace the QMainWindow there with QWidget, it should and will display